# How do I do a kiosk mode of the nativescript-vue project

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

nativescript-vue project on industrial android tablet (4.4.2), full-screen and kiosk how can I run in detail can you provide information? (helloworld application)

Comment: Please read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Check out the [SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014879/kiosk-mode-in-nativescript-for-android-app) and [Forum](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/android-kiosk-mode-single-app-mode/3186). There is no easy way to do this, you have to do it by accessing the native apis.

Comment: How do I access the API?

Comment: Can you just develop a "normal" app and run it using one of these apps that make the android tablet run in kiosk mode: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kiosk